# django: Cannot create bounded form with ImageField

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-views

I have a class based view:

```
class RecordView(View):
    record_form = RecordForm
    record_form_data = {}
    templare = 'acquisition.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fil = urllib.urlopen('/home/student/wwww.jpg')
        ddic = {'small_cover': SimpleUploadedFile('hehe.jpg', fil.read())}
        rr_form = self.record_form(self.record_form_data, ddic)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'rr_form': rr_form,
                                                })
```

I did this according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form).

But i cannot see anything on form in 'small_cover' image field.
And after data is post `request.FILES` also give empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a value for `<input type="file">` due to security reasons.

The docs at your link talks about processing `POST` data and tells nothing about providing file data to `GET` request.

Comment: please see the code under #Bound form with ImageField. This is ofcourse for get. Really getting confused

Comment: Nope. "Bound" form is a form with a `POST` data. You confused this data with `initial` argument of a form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values